# How do I properly turn a statement into a mathematical proposition?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given the statement: Every natural number is odd

I have to turn this statement into a mathematical proposition. I also have to write up its negation as well (where the $\neg$ doesn't show up in the final answer).

Steps I took:

$$N(x) : x \in\mathbb{N},\quad k \in\mathbb{Z}$$

$$\forall x(N(x)\rightarrow \exists k(N(k)\wedge x=2k+1))$$

Negation: $\neg \forall x(N(x)\rightarrow \exists k(N(k)\wedge x=2k+1))$

$$\Rightarrow\exists x\neg (N(x)\rightarrow \exists k(N(k)\wedge x=2k+1))$$

$$\Rightarrow\exists x (N(x)\wedge\neg \exists k(N(k)\wedge x=2k+1))$$

$$\Rightarrow\exists x (N(x)\wedge \forall k \neg (N(k)\wedge x = 2k+1))$$

$$\Rightarrow\exists x (N(x)\wedge \forall k(N(k)\rightarrow x\neq 2k+1))$$

I'm almost positive about my answer, but my problem is that I don't truly understand what I did here because I just went off or things I saw in the MIT OCW lecture notes to try and formulate this. One of the drawbacks to self studying is not being able to get something clarified when I don't understand. I am hoping that someone here can break down a few things for me here (in layman terms).

Why was $N(x)$ used? Why couldn't I just use $x\in\mathbb{N}$ ? I don't understand why I had to create a function in order to represent the $\mathbb{N}$. I would also like understand the predicate to this statement. I wrote it up that way because another example contained a similar format. I would like to know why it had to use the $\wedge$ operator.

Please break it down to me in layman terms. I'm not used to this type of math and MIT's Math for CS is my first exposure to Discrete Math. (Although I know that some people here might argue that it's barely scratching the surface of discrete math).

Comment: Small typo, the second right parenthesis should be erased.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Would you please be able to point out where exactly?

Comment: Second displayed formula starts with $\forall x(N(x))\to$. It should start with $\forall x(N(x)\to$.

Comment: The last step is wrong; from $¬∃k(N(k)∧x=2k+1)$ to $∀k¬(N(k)∧x=2k+1)$ to $∀k(N(k)→x≠2k+1)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Why put a parentheses at all then? Would you be able to explain why $N(x)$ is used represent the natural numbers?

Comment: By the definition of well-formed formula we need a parenthesis. The formal language we are using has predicate symbols and function symbols and constant symbols. We don't want to bring in $\in$ and the whole apparatus of set theory.  The $N(x)$ could however be dispensed with if the default interpretation of quantifiers is that they range over the natural numbers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is it wrong to use $N(x)$ considering the way I defined it? I deleted the extra parentheses. Please let me know if that is the correct format.

Comment: It is fine.  I would prefer an ordinary language definition, we write $N(x)$ for "$x$ is a natural number."

Comment: @AndréNicolas I fixed my mistake pointed out by the other person. Please take a look at it, if you can. In addition,would you please be able to sum up the things you found wrong and what could be improved in an answer? It would really help me. I will +1 and accept it.

Comment: There is a missing right parenthesis at the end of the second displayed line. And it continues to be missing all along. I am not really worried about it. I was worried about the earlier extra parenthesis, because it changed the entire meaning. Apart from that everything is fine. Except that $x\ne 2k+1$ is a hidden $\lnot$. That's sort of OK, since negation cannot be dispensed with, unless the logical language has a symbol for false. It is Mauro Allegranza who should, if he wishes, write an answer.

Comment: Where exactly is this missing right parenthesis? Here? $\forall x(N(x)\rightarrow \exists k(N(k)\wedge x=2k+1)$ I'm sorry for bugging you while trying to perfect this.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer - you have the leftmost parentheses unmatched; the formula must be : $∀x(N(x)→∃k(N(k)∧x=2k+1))$ due to the fact that the scope of the leading universal quantifier is the complete formula, i.e. also the occurrence of $x$ in $x=2k+1$ must be **into** the scope of $\forall x$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me that you could just write $\forall x\in \mathbf{N} \exists k\in \mathbf{N}\cup \{0\} \hspace{0.5cm} \mbox{such that} \hspace {0.5cm} x=2k+1$

Comment: The problem specifically stated that I need to start by putting a $\neg$ outside of the initial statement and work it inside.